# Programmatic check to prevent piracy of my Azure VMI solution software

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I searched and couldn't find a programmatic way (using c#) to check whether customer is being charged for my software provisioned as VMI offering on Azure Marketplace. This code would run from within the very same software check is done for, i.e. software self-check upon start.

Essentially, I'm trying to prevent the following scenario: Step 1) Customer provisions my VMI software solution. Step 2) Customer then provisions a separate 'clean' VM and copies my software to it. Step 3) Customer then cancels my VMI solution subscription and continues running my software in Azure on 'clean' VM without paying for it.

I already know how to check whether my software is running in Azure (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable && !RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated) but that does not check for charges. I could introduce license files, etc, but then management of those would be a hassle to all customers - essentially forcing BYOL-like situation on all. Thus I'm looking for a generic solution without my own customers DB or individual license files - if possible. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: I would create azure function which accepts mac address, number of cpu, memory + some extra details to verify license. This would prevent users to just copy since new machine will have new details.

Comment: What I've learned no matter what you do anything can be hacked, in my app fortunately I have online service and offline software so if you hack offline, its not fully working without online, yes you can use it but with many limitations

Comment: @ Volodymyr My thinking is along the following lines: Azure already knows that there are both software and infrastructure costs for provisioned VMI, while plain VM would only have infrastructure cost, thus the only thing needed detected would be presence/lack of the software costs for the VM instance. Ideally, my software would simply just call some existing standard billing Azure API and get the list of the software cost with SKU for the VM it's running under. That'd be all what's needed. No software costs = software pirated OR there are software costs = software runs legit if SKU matches.

Comment: @ Volodymyr P.S. MAC, cpu etc are all essentially individual license type of protection, i.e. huge hassle I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Have you tried to talk with Azure devs? Tweet to @AzureSupport they will give you some contacts to help with that

Comment: @ Volodymyr I'm not an official vendor yet - just figuring things out 1st before I go for it. I'm hoping that MS has some of those devs roaming here looking for questions like mine.